# Reinforcement Learning: Continuous actions with multiple parameters

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm doing some RL work for a battle environment. I'm facing some problem about continuous action space with multiple parameters.

The action space can be described like:

Action 1: `MoveTo(x, y)`; it means the agent will move to the target coordinate (x, y). x and y are continuous.

Action 2: `Shoot(x, y, z)`; it means the agent will shoot in the direction (x,y,z). x/y/z are continuous too.

This action space is whether discrete or continuous? And each action has multiple parameters.Is there some algorithms dealing with the problem? Or some similar environment solutions.

Any advice will be grateful.Thanks.